# Django number of objects added today

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I have a models.py like this:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)


    def get_absolute_url(self, ):
        return reverse('baslik', args=[self.slug])

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['updated']



class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    baslik = models.ForeignKey(Baslik, null=True, blank=True)
    icerik = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.icerik)
```

I need to display number of Entries added in current date for every baslik which is ForeignKey of it. I use this views.py:

```
def hepsi(request):
    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')  
    rast = Entry.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    gunlist = []
    zaman1 = date.today()
    zaman2 = str(zaman1).split(" ")
    zamangun = zaman2[0]

    for i in basliklar:
        entryler = i.entry_set.all()
        sayi2 = entryler.count()

        if sayi2>0:
            ent1 = entryler.latest('id')
            ent2 = ent1.updated
            ent3 = str(ent2).split(" ")
            entgun = ent3[0]

            if entgun == zamangun:
                gunlist.append(i)

        if sayi2==0:
            baslik1 = i.updated
            baslik2 = str(baslik1).split(" ")
            baslikgun = baslik2[0]

            if baslikgun==zamangun:
                gunlist.append(i)

    cta = {'basliklar': basliklar, 'entryler': entryler, 'ent1': ent1, 'ent2': ent2, 'entgun': entgun, 'zamangun': zamangun, 'gunlist': gunlist, 'rast': rast}

    return render(request, "base.html", cta)
```

and I need the number of entries added today in this part of base.html in for loop:

{% for i in gunlist %}

```
 {{ i }} {{ # of entries added today }}
```

{% endfor %}

How can I solve this? Any opinions would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is for views.py:

```
all_basliks=Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')

for baslik in all_basliks:
 number=baslik.Entry_set.filter(timestamp=localtime.date()).count()
 gunlist[baslik]=number

return render(request, 'gunlist': gunlist)
```

In base.html:

```
{% for i in gunlist %}
 {{ i }} {{ gunlist_i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It says: AttributeError at /
'Baslik' object has no attribute 'Entry_set'

Comment: I changed the 'Entry' to 'entry' and it did not raise any errors but it still doesn't do what I want.

Comment: You are right. It should have been "entry_set". baslik.entry_set.all() should return all the entries, the given baslik is referenced from. filter(timestamp=localtime.date()) should filter out only those entries, which were created today. count() returns the count of such entries.

Answer (score 0):

This version of hepsi funct with OrderedDict is working fine.

```
def hepsi(request):
    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated') 
    rast = Entry.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    gunlist = OrderedDict([])
    zaman1 = date.today()
    zaman2 = str(zaman1).split(" ")
    zamangun = zaman2[0]

    for i in basliklar:
        entryler = i.entry_set.all()
        sayi2 = entryler.count()

        if sayi2>0:
            j=0
            for enty in entryler:
                entyy1 = enty.updated
                entyy2 = str(entyy1).split(" ")
                entyygun = entyy2[0]
                if entyygun == zamangun:
                    j += 1
            gunlist.update({i:j})

        if sayi2==0:
            baslik1 = i.updated
            baslik2 = str(baslik1).split(" ")
            baslikgun = baslik2[0]

            if baslikgun==zamangun:
                gunlist.update({i:'0'})

    cta = {'basliklar': basliklar, 'entryler': entryler, 'entyygun': entyygun, 'zamangun': zamangun, 'gunlist': gunlist.iteritems(), 'rast': rast}

    return render(request, "base.html", cta)
```